# WebConfig with target environment middle word

Tags: .net, web-applications, web-config

I've inherited an application, which has the following hierarchy of web.config.

[image: *enter image description here*]

The middle word corresponds to the DropDownList values of Solution Configurations in Standard toolbar.

I've asked around but didn't find any useful information about what this methodology is called or where I can get more information about this.

Please let me know or point me to a resource which could explain this in a little more detail as it appears to be a useful architectural aspect.

Thanks all.

Comment: they are called config transforms.

Comment: Those are web config transformations: an easy way of changing your webconfig to reflect particular configurartion need. You can read more at http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are a VS2010+ feature called config transforms. You can read about them here.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'll select an answer once I'll be allowed to do.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2010 and above, you have the ability to apply a transformation on web.config depending on the build configuration. Have a look at this:

http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/web-deployment-webconfig-transformation_23.html#!/2009/03/web-deployment-webconfig-transformation_23.html